# Weather web part for SharePoint 2019 on-premises Modern Page

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, modern-experience, 2019, modern-pages

How to add Weather web part for SharePoint 2019 on-premises Modern Page because it is required to be used in Internal SharePoint server 2019 - Modern Site.

Answer (score 0):

> The Weather web part is **not available** in SharePoint Server 2019.

It is available only for SharePoint in Microsoft 365 (online) & Office for business

**Documentation**: [Show the weather on your page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-the-weather-on-your-page-4a86540e-0846-4fc0-bad0-1a82fcd430fc)

Comment: We need to implement the weather web part in SharePoint Server 2019, which weather API service can rely on it to build custom web part and pass the city as parameter.

Comment: If you see the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-the-weather-on-your-page-4a86540e-0846-4fc0-bad0-1a82fcd430fc), Microsoft uses **MSN Weather** API.

Comment: For you requirements, you have to build the SPFx web part, you can check this [web part sample](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-weather-information) to get started with it (it uses Yahoo weather API).

Comment: Hi @SaeedZaki, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if this helped you in any way.